# Executing Maven unit tests with classpath set to generated project JAR

Tags: java, maven, classpath

Some unit tests in my application are related to finding and manipulating certain files resources that are part of the application itself.
I need these tests to be executed in the real production setting of the application, where it is deployed as a JAR file, not as an exploded directory.

How could I instruct Maven to execute my unit tests considering as the classpath the project generated jar file (and any other declared library dependencies) instead of the compiled classes in the file system as it does by default?.

In other words, right now the classpath for my unit tests is set to: `/$PROJECTPATH/target/classes/`.

Instead, I would like this classpath to be set to: `/$PROJECTPATH/target/myjarfile.jar`.

I have tried manually adding and removing dependency classes, as explained here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html
,but until now it is not working.

My current project POM looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
      ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version> 
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>

        <configuration>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution> 
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <!-- <phase>package</phase>  -->
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>

          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        <configuration>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                <classpathDependencyExclude>
                  ${project.build.outputDirectory}
                </classpathDependencyExclude>
              </classpathDependencyExcludes>

              <additionalClasspathElements>
                <additionalClasspathElement>
              ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
                </additionalClasspathElement>
              </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!.

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401857/using-maven-to-build-separate-jar-files-for-unit-testing-a-custom-class-loader. The requirement is different (in that the OP specifically wants the JARs to be *off* the classpath), but perhaps it will provide some hints.

Comment: Did you get this problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

The standard unit tests executed as part of the test lifecycle phase cannot see the project JAR because the `test` phase is executed before the `package` phase, so your tests are run before Maven generates the JAR.  See [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for a list of lifecycle phases and their order.

What you want it to run your tests as integration tests, which execute in the `integration-test` phase.

There are a number of tutorials for setting up Maven to run integration tests.  [Here](http://onjavahell.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/integration-testing-with-maven-20.html) and [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) are a couple of starters.  The [failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) is typically used for executing integration tests.

I can't recall exactly if integration tests use `target/classes` or your project's JAR file in the classpath.  But if it doesn't you could always create another Maven project, add your tests in there and add the main project as a dependency to this integration test project.  In some cases this can be preferable to using the integration test phase in the main project if it is not just a standard Java library, for example if you are writing an annotation processor.

Comment: +1 thanks for the clarification, but uff, this simple problem is getting more complex of what I expected. One question, your answer explains why the jar cannot be ADDED to the classpath, but it does not explain why ${project.build.outputDirectory} is not excluded from the classpath (the tests succeed using that classpath), is there something wrong with my classpathDependencyExclude elements ?

Comment: ClasspathDependencyExcludes only exclude *dependencies* and they take the form `groupId:artifactId`.  It might work if you set plugin configuration option `classesDirectory`, which by default is ${project.build.outputDirectory}, to some other directory that does not exist so that your classes directory is not included on the classpath.