# Test the packaged artifact with Maven failsafe

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

In my Maven/Java project, I want to make sure that I always get the loading of resources right -- some can be always fetched as Files, others get packaged into the final `.jar` and have to be fetched as streams.

I now would have thought that this is the ideal task for the Maven failsafe plugin: I simply JUnit-test the affected methods in the Unit tests (means, that the tests are run using the classes lying in the classes folder) using surefire and in the integration tests (means, the tests are run using the classes packed into the jar) using surefire.

But when I make a demo project that throws an Exception when run from the `.jar` and doesn't when run from Eclipse, both the unit tests and the integration tests calling the method do not throw an exception, means that **failsafe doesn't use the packaged jar at all**.

How can I tie it to the jar artifact only?

My `pom.xml`:

```
<project ...>
    ...

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>packagingTest.MainClass</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ... Dependency to JUnit ...
</project>
```

Comment: maven-failsafe-plugin is bound to the integration-test phase but does not offer access to the created jar which has been packaged in the package phase. This needed to be handled by the appropriate integration test.

Comment: So the maven-failsafe-plugin is just the wrong plugin? Which one would be the correct one then?

Comment: No the plugin is the right one but you have to handle the usage of the jar file yourself...The question if what you like to do the package jar file? Run command line app ? If yes than you might take a look at the exec-maven-plugin...

Comment: Okay, now I at least understand what "This needed to be handled by the appropriate integration test." means. :-D In my minimal example noted above, I would just call the main method and see if it crashes, but in the "real problem" I have an application with a Swing GUI: In the integration tests, I use AssertJ to test the GUI functionality with simulated user input and assertions about the displayed messages, data etc. So the task would be to launch the GUI `@Before` the tests and kill it `@After`wards.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I think this question is a duplicate of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12198047/6403504